# Jquery slide page to the bottom

Tags: jquery

I have a question related to jQuery. I have a comment box which is toggled using jQuery when a button is clicked.

The problem I am having is that the button is on the top of the page and the form is on the very bottom, so if someone clicks the button they can't see that the comment box has been toggled. Is there any way that once they click the submit comment button the page will drag itself to bottom so they can see the form?

Answer (score 1):

you can add the ID (ex. **yourformid**) to the form and do the redirect like: **http://yoururl#yourformid**. In this page will move down to the form

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll there in **animated fashion** like this:

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#elementID').offset().top
  });
});
```

Just replace `#elementID` with the id of element present at the bottom you want to scroll to.

Make sure to wrap your code in ready handler:

```
$(function(){
    $('#buttonID').click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#elementID').offset().top
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks sarfraz you made my day dude, and can you explain aswell how it's working actually coz i am not a jquery geek

Comment: @Shanon: jQuery's `animate` function is pretty flexible you can use to create your own custom animations. Here we specify the `top` position of the element to scroll to. The `animate` function helps you scroll there in animated way.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to change your `button` element to `a` element because `button` is especially for form submit in HTML, and `a` element could be used to navigation inside document.

so when you have an `a` element, place an **id** attribute on your comment box such as:

```
<div id="commentBox"></div>
```

then put an **href** attribute on the previous `a` element, the value should be `#commentBox` so the element may looks like:

```
<a href="#commentBox" onclick="$('#commentBox').show();">Text</a>
```

This solution utilizes browser's function to navigate to the comment box, thus it may be the most standard way although it cannot implement an animation for scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchors and then animate the scroll, very much like the answer of Sarfaz:

```
function goToByScroll(id){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
<script>
    goToByScroll("theIdIWantToGoTo");
</script>
```

Demo: http://djpate.com/portfolio/scrollTop/

Source: http://djpate.com/2009/10/07/animated-scroll-to-anchorid-function-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

simply use anchor like:

```
<a href="#formone" onclick="showform()">Form</a>
<form id="formone">....</form>
```